# How to get errors thrown by a modelform when the validation fails?

Tags: django, validation, modelform

I have a model `Genre` (for songs) that has unique constraint on a CharField. I am using a `ModelForm` `GenreForm` bound to the model. So whenever the `form.is_valid()` fails (due to duplicate entry or other reasons) how do I get these error details? 
I have checked `form.non_field_errors` , but does not give me much information.

Comment: Have you looked at `form.errors`?

Comment: Have you checked the docs on validation?..

Answer (score 0):

```
def view_fun(request):
    ......
    if form.isvalid():
        # do something
    else:
        print form.errors # this will print all the validation errors
```